# JSF 2.0 Ajax listener in SelectOneMenu tag is not working

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

***PROBLEM SOLVED!!***
There was a validationerror on my backing bean telling me something like this:
Conversion Error setting value 'Africa (AFR)' for 'null Converter'.

Because of the JSF lifesycle the listener method on my backingbean wasn't called

---

I'm havinga problem with JSF2.
I have a selectOneMenu tag with an ajax tag that should fire a listener when its value is changed. The xhtml page looks like the following (stripped some things out)

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectedContinent" value="#{searchExtendedAction.destination.continent}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{searchExtendedAction.continents}" />
            <f:ajax render="locationSelector" listener="#{searchExtendedAction.doUpdateLocations}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In my backing bean I have the following (Left some properties out):

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SearchExtendedAction implements Serializable{


// Left some properties out


    @Valid
    private Location departure;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.err.println("INIT called");
        allContinents = continentService.getAllContinents();
    }

    @EJB
    private ContinentService continentService;

    public void doExtendedSearch()
    {
        System.err.println("SEARCH");
    }
    public void doUpdateLocations(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
    {
        System.err.println("BONZAI");
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getContinents()
    {
        List<SelectItem> continents= new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        continents.add(new SelectItem("--- Select Continent ---"));

        for(Continent c : continentService.getAllContinents()){
            continents.add(new SelectItem(c.getName()));
        }

        return continents;
    }
}
```

Now when I pick a value from my selectOneMenu a HTTP Post is fired. And I know this because my PostConstruct method is called and the message pops up in my console. But the listener is not called. And I have no idea why.

Some more information about the technologies I'm using:

```
16:21:08,282 INFO  [AbstractServer] Starting: JBossAS [6.1.0.Final "Neo"]
16:21:11,725 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.7.0,Oracle Corporation
16:21:11,725 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
16:21:11,725 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 21.0-b17,Oracle Corporation
16:21:11,726 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,amd64
16:21:19,067 INFO  [AbstractServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 3.4.1.GA
16:21:19,981 INFO  [JSFImplManagementDeployer] Initialized 3 JSF configurations: [Mojarra-1.2, MyFaces-2.0, Mojarra-2.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Now when I pick a value from my selectOneMenu a HTTP Post is fired. And I know this because my PostConstruct method is called and the message pops up in my console.*

It is not normal that the `@PostConstruct` of a session scoped bean is fired at that moment. It should be fired only once during bean's construction whenever you request the view for the first time in the session. Are you sure that the `@SessionScoped` is of type `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` and thus **not** `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`?

**Update**: as per the comments, that issue has been fixed. However, it didn't solve the concrete problem of the listener not being invoked. It turns out that a validation error has occurred. That can happen when the `equals()` method of the selected item doesn't return `true` for any of the items in the list during the apply request values phase. You could get the exact validation error by supplying a

```xml
<h:messages id="messages" />
```

and include its ID in the `render` attribute

```xml
<f:ajax render="locationSelector messages" ... />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `@ViewScoped` is a better choice for this. This way every browser window/tab within the same browser session has its own instance of the bean. A session scoped the bean is namely shared between all browser windows/tabs within the same session which may lead to "wtf?" behaviour which is thus bad for User Experience.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip, and the import was indeed wrong. INIT is called once now but the listener still isn't working :(

Comment: Make sure that you've a `<h:head>` (I think you have as POST is seemingly fired) and that you don't nest multiple `<h:form>`s in each other (behaviour is unspecified and browser dependent).

Comment: Yea thats ok, I tried it with primefaces ajax tag and still not working :(. The result I got is:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="searchForm:locationSelector"><![CDATA[<select id="searchForm:locationSelector" name="searchForm:locationSelector" size="1"></select>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[2083572417093636307:6166663626932858824]]></update></changes><extension primefacesCallbackParam="validationFailed">{"validationFailed":true}</extension></partial-response>

Comment: The `"validationFailed":true` hints that validation has failed. Add `<h:messages id="messages" />` to the view and add that `id` to the `render` attribute of `<f:ajax>`. Big change that you see a `Validation error: Value Not Valid`. This has been answered in detail zillion of times here on SO :)

Comment: Aha, so that is how you show validationMessages Thanks. There is a converter issue :)